# how to get the coordinates of a layout?

Tags: android

Here is the code that inflates bulbs. I need the co ordinates of all the bulbs on the basis of their id provided.

```
public void Bulb() {
for(int i=0;i<bulbFlag;i++){
        bulb = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bulb_layout, null);
        bulb.setId(1010+i);

        final ImageView bulbip = bulb.findViewById(R.id.bulbip);
        bulbip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (bulbOp) {
                    case 0:
                        bulbip.setImageResource(R.mipmap.connect1);
                        bulbOp = 1;
                        setBulb_glow();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        bulbip.setImageResource(R.mipmap.connect);
                        bulbOp = 0;
                        setBulb_glow();
                        break;
                    default:
                        bulbip.setImageResource(R.mipmap.connect);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
        workbench_layout.addView(bulb);
      }
}
```